# generating thumbnail image for video

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, video-processing, expression-encoder

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 on Windows 7. I want to use Expression Encoder 3 to generate thumbnail image for video (wmv format) every 30 seconds -- e.g. for a 5 minutes video, there will be 10 thumbnails which reflects video at the time of 0 second, 30 second, 1 minute, 1 minute and 30 seconds, etc.

Any reference code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440765(v=Expression.10).aspx) you could try using the [GetThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.audiovideofile.getthumbnail(v=Expression.30).aspx) method:

```
var video = new MediaItem(filePath);
using (var bitmap = video.MainMediaFile.GetThumbnail(
    new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), 
    new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480)))
{
    // do something with the bitmap like:
    bitmap.Save("thumb1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. Any workarounds for when the encoder cannot find a codec for a specific file, though? Just that I'm running into problems with MP4s.

Comment: @George2 link not found (to SO)